# django rest framework - GET request for list of IDs

Tags: python, django, rest, redux, es6-promise

Using isomorphic fetch in react-redux to retrieve data from Django Rest Framework.

I'd like to send DRF a GET request with an array of PKs and get back their records.

From what I've read so far on StackOverflow, request bodies are not necessarily RESTful, it's too unwieldy to pass a large array in my url params, so I can only conclude that I need to do a POST or PUT request.

The bottom answer seems to be successful in sending a GET with a request.body, but I haven't been able to serialize the data

[Request multiple ids from Django REST framework API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876275/request-multiple-ids-from-django-rest-framework-api)

What's the best practice for retrieving data from DRF given some kind of user input?

TLDR:

1. Do I initiate a GET (not RESTful, but it intuitively makes more sense)
2. Do I POST? (update records showing that these records have been "viewed" and then serialize a response?)
3. Something else?

Comment: This answer should help inform your decision: http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1720161

Comment: Yup I read that. Since the GET doesn't follow the 1.1 spec and I POST, is that even restful? I'm attempting to search data. Therefore for large querysets, getting data is considered a POST?

Comment: From what I know, I'd say searching isn't enough to consider it a POST. If the request changes something, then it would be a POST. However if it is simply to retrieve data, even if work is done to retrieve that data, I would consider it a GET.

Comment: makes sense: it'd be wise to consider it a GET. Thus in order to keep it restful, I'd send a large GET request in the url params?

Comment: As shown in the answer you linked, yes