# correct DRF filter list view endpoint to return multiple objects by id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I want to be able to request multiple db objects by id in a single DRF request via url parameter with a GET request. I read through [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876275/request-multiple-ids-from-django-rest-framework-api/32876443) and DRF's docs on [filtering against query parameters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) and thought I understood how to implement but my solution is a little off. It will return a response, but isn't filtering the queryset (multiple id response is `{"detail":"Not found."}`)

views.py

```
@permission_classes((HasAPIAccess, HasUnrestrictedAPIAccess, ))
class EventListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    queryset = Event.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        ids = self.request.query_params.get('ids', None)
        if ids is not None:
            ids = [ int(x) for x in ids.split(',') ]
            queryset = Event.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)

        else:
            queryset = Event.objects.all()[0:10]

        return queryset
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'events', EventViewSet)

my_patterns = [
    url(r'^events/list/$',
        EventListView.as_view(),
        name='events-by-id'),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/v1/')),
    url(r'^v1/$', schema_view),
    url(r'^v1/', include(my_patterns)),
]`
```

the goal is to make a GET request like `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Api-Key: {{ key }}' 'http://api.foo.com/v1/events/list/?ids=1,2,3,4,5'` but currently that's returning `{"detail":"Not found."}` response

a `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Api-Key: {{ key }}' 'http://api.foo.com/v1/events/list/'` request with no params returns the unfiltered queryset

Comment: unrelated but in class-based views you should define the `permission_classes` as properties of the class, not as a decorator. `permission_classes =[HasAPIAccess, HasUnrestrictedAPIAccess]`

Comment: thanks, good to know

Answer (score 1):

figured out the issue, only needed to define the queryset in the method and it was an err to define it earlier. once I remved `queryset = Event.objects.all()` the view and url route work correctly

```
class EventListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ids = self.request.query_params.get('ids', None)
        if ids is not None:
            ids = [ int(x) for x in ids.split(',') ]
            queryset = Event.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)

        else:
            queryset = Event.objects.all()[0:10]

        return queryset
```